# How do I get the relevant string match that is associated for a given string?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, f5

For the output below from Data1, I want to create a regular expression that can help me identify that POOLNAME2 is associated to KNOWNSERVER2. POOLNAME1 is not associated to KNOWNSERVER2. POOLNAME1 is associated to KNOWNSERVER1.

```
ltm pool POOLNAME1 {
    load-balancing-mode least-connections-member
    members {
        KNOWNSERVER1
ltm pool POOLNAME2 {
    load-balancing-mode least-connections-member
    members {
        KNOWNSERVER2
```

This regex works:

```
match = re.findall( r'ltm pool POOLNAME2.*KNOWNSERVER', data1, re.DOTALL )
```

But this regex doesn't work the way I want it to (which is that it should provide me the same result as the previous one):

```
match = re.findall( r'ltm pool .*KNOWNSERVER', data1, re.DOTALL )
```

Instead, it would give me the entire string below...

> ltm pool POOLNAME1 {
>       load-balancing-mode least-connections-member
>       members {
>           KNOWNSERVER1 ltm pool POOLNAME2 {
>       load-balancing-mode least-connections-member
>       members {
>           KNOWNSERVER2

The match that is relevant is POOLNAME2 and not POOLNAME1.

Comment: Correction: match = re.findall( r'ltm pool POOLNAME2.*KNOWNSERVER2', data1, re.DOTALL )

Comment: Don't fix in comments - fix in question body. And, please, format you code/data properly - it hurts my eyes just to look at your post.

Comment: Correction: match = re.findall( r'ltm pool .*KNOWNSERVER2', data1, re.DOTALL )

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand the question ? what I understand your question to be is, you have a defined virtual IP address, 
and two pools with names POOLNAME1 and POOLNAME2, with the least load balancing algorithm used.

I am predicting that, you have multiple servers that are grouped into servicing different requests. What I recommend is 
you put the first group of servers in a pool and give them a name eg: POOLNAME1, and the second group of servers will be put
in a second pool with POOLNAME2.

=== > To answer what I think is the main core of this question, I suggest you use an i-Rule and associate the i-Rule with the
 virtual server associated With the use of these two pools, the i-Rule will provide the logic required to select the appropriate pool 
and the flexibility to incorporate much more. I gave you two sample examples of i-Rules. Below is an
explanation of what the i-Rules do.

### i-Rule-1:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
   set URI [string tolower [HTTP::uri]]
   if { $URI starts_with "/<uri-name"}{
      pool <POOL_NAME>
   } else {reject}
}
```

This i-Rule satifies an http request and will send the request to a particular poolname if the URI which is part of the request string consists of 
the defined name. In this case the name in the script is generic (uri-name).

So let say you access the url   http://pptesting.kno.agc.com/chico

in the request above  (uri-name) will replace "chico", so the i-Rule will send the request to the servers in the pool with pool 
name POOLNAME1 (POOL_NAME in the script) and reject any more request after that. I am assuming this is the logic in your question.

The second i-Rule below adds a bit more to the logic flow.

### i-Rule-2:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  if {([ string tolower [HTTP::uri]] starts_with "/<uri>" ) } { pool POOLNAME1 }
     else { pool POOLNAME2 }
```

This i-Rule satifies an http request and will send the request to a primary pool with name POOLNAME1 and if this pool is not available it will send the request to
POOLNAME2. The pools are only reference only if the "uri" starts with a defined string. In this case the "uri" will be similar to "chico" in the example above

I hope I was able to answer your questions, let me know if you intended to relay an different reasoning.